How to make bubble and Time in react-native-gifted-chat side by side
When I implemented it, bubble and Time were split into left and right ends.

Actual source code
  <View style={styles.incomingContainer}>
    <Bubble
      {...props}
      containerStyle={{
        right: {
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          borderColor: "red",
          borderWidth: 1,
        },
      }}
      renderTime={() => null}
    />
    {renderTime(props)}
  </View>

I want to put Bubble and time next to each other without opening the margin as shown in the image.


It seems to be an issue caused by the View(incomingContainer) being too wide. Could you try modifying the properties of the parent view or the properties of the incomingContainer?
